# How to collect multiple data in a table then output like a concatenated string it in LUA

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I am totally new to LUA scripting and trying to create a table with a data received one by one then use it in same function to output collected data.

```
function PremadeFrame_OnEvent(self, event, arg1, arg2)
  --start chat_msg_raid_leader
  if (event == "CHAT_MSG_RAID" or event == "CHAT_MSG_RAID_LEADER" ) then
    battlegrounds = {};
    if string.find(arg1,"BGNUMBER") then
      number = string.match(arg1,"%d+");
      battlegrounds[number] = "";
      battlegrounds[number] = battlegrounds[number]..","..arg2;
      for k,v in pairs(battlegrounds) do
      DEFAULT_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage ("\124c0000FFFF[BG Number:"..k.."]"..v.."");
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to add data end of other data by using

```
battlegrounds[number] = battlegrounds[number]..","..arg2;
```

but it outputs only one data received, example first player name is Scarill and others are John, Max, it gets data from Scarill,John,Max but outputs like

```
[BG Number 43], Scarill
```

I want it to output like

```
[BG Number 43] Scarill, Max
[BG Number 54] John
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `PremadeFrame_OnEvent` is a event callback function. On each call new `battlegrounds` table is created inside so it's natural that it have only one item in it. It you want to capture more than current item, you need to make `battlegrounds` external to `PremadeFrame_OnEvent` like this:

```
battlegrounds = {}

function PremadeFrame_OnEvent(self, event, arg1, arg2)
  --start chat_msg_raid_leader
  if (event == "CHAT_MSG_RAID" or event == "CHAT_MSG_RAID_LEADER" ) then
    if string.find(arg1,"BGNUMBER") then
      number = string.match(arg1,"%d+")
      battlegrounds[number] = arg2
      for k,v in pairs(battlegrounds) do
        DEFAULT_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage ("\124c0000FFFF[BG Number:"..k.."]"..v.."")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

so it is not recreated each time in event handler.

Comment: i thought same thing at start, since i come from another scripting language when you declare something outside function you must make it global or something like that. i did what you said but now it returns empty

Comment: @Sercankd I've updated code a bit ago (notice `battlegrounds[number] = arg2`) see if that changes the output.

Comment: i think there is an another problem, the data received is not instant and not simultaneous. i guess there is a problem with collecting everything

Comment: @Sercankd yes, it's hard to tell what is wrong without more context information. But at least know you know that was wrong in your first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the string every time the event handler is called:

```
local battlegrounds = {}

function PremadeFrame_OnEvent(self, event, arg1, arg2)
  --start chat_msg_raid_leader
  if (event == "CHAT_MSG_RAID" or event == "CHAT_MSG_RAID_LEADER" ) then
    if string.find(arg1,"BGNUMBER") then
      number = string.match(arg1,"%d+")
      if battlegrounds[number] == nil then
          battlegrounds[number] = arg2
      else
          battlegrounds[number] = battlegrounds[number] .. "," .. arg2
      end
      for k,v in ...
```

But if `PremadeFrame_OnEvent()` can be called multiple times with same `arg1` and `arg2`, but you duplicates in string, then your need your battlegrounds[number] to be a table and only add `arg2` if not already in that table. Example (not tested, may be syntax errors):

```
local battlegrounds = {}

function PremadeFrame_OnEvent(self, event, arg1, arg2)
  --start chat_msg_raid_leader
  if (event == "CHAT_MSG_RAID" or event == "CHAT_MSG_RAID_LEADER" ) then
    if string.find(arg1,"BGNUMBER") then
      local number = string.match(arg1,"%d+")
      if battlegrounds[number] == nil then
          battlegrounds[number] = {[arg2] = 1} -- use hash map, will be easiest to search for arg2 later
      else
          -- only add arg2 if not already in there:
          local bgn = battlegrounds[number] 
          if bgn[arg2] == nil then
              table.insert(bgn, arg2)
          end
      end

      for k,v in pairs(battlegrounds) do
          local msg = "\124c0000FFFF[BG Number:" .. k .. "]" .. table.concat(v, ',')
          DEFAULT_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage(msg)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Stylistic note: try to use `local` always except if need global